# Extracting substring using R

Tags: r, regex, substring

I want to extract substring (description details) from the following strings:

```
string1 <- @{self=https://somesite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/1; description=The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it.; iconUrl=https://somesite.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/open.png; name=Open; id=1; statusCategory=}
string2 <- @{self=https://somesite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10203; description=; iconUrl=https://somesite.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png; name=Full Curation; id=10203; statusCategory=}
```

I am trying to get the following

```
ExtractedSubString1 = "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it."
ExtractedSubString2 = ""
```

I tried this:

```
library(stringr)    
ExtractedSubString1 <- substr(string1, str_locate(string1, "description=")+12, str_locate(string1, "; iconUrl")-1)
ExtractedSubString2 <- substr(string2, str_locate(string2, "description=")+12, str_locate(string2, "; iconUrl")-1)
```

Looking for a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: "Better" in what sense?

Comment: Like alternate code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only base R's `sub` and back referencing, you could do

```
sub(".*description=(.*?);.*", "\\1", c(string1, string2))
[1] "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it." ""
```

The `".*"` match any set of characters, `"description="` is a literal match, `".*?"` matches any set of characters, but the `?` forces a lazy match rather than a greedy match. `";"` is a literal, and the `"()"` capture the sub-expression that is lazily matched. The back reference `"\\1"` returns the sub-expression captured in the parentheses.

Using the base R functions `regexec` and `regmatches`gets a bit closer to the method in the OP. `sapply` with `"["` is then used to extract the desired result.

```
sapply(regmatches(c(string1, string2),
                  regexec(".*description=(.*?);.*", c(string1, string2))),
       "[", 2)
[1] "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it." ""
```

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the task and a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
test.1 <- gsub("description=", "", strsplit(string1, "; ")[[1]][2])

test.2 <- gsub("description=", "", strsplit(string2, "; ")[[1]][2])
```

This simply splits the string on `;` which divides each string in to 6 elements the square brackets select the 2nd element and the gsub replaces the `description=` to nothing to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an useful alternate approach. This will be very handy while manipulating strings from json output.